# I want to scroll the entire page when clicked on List Tile

Tags: listview, flutter, scroll

I have a list View wrapped in another List View. The inner List View should not be scrollable I want that when the User off the App clicks on the List Tile the whole Page scrolls down. So the Top disappears and the User can see the rest of the List View. For now this is possible, but only when the user clicks on the little Edge of the outer screen. When someone clicks on the ListTile directyl nothing happens.

This is the outer List View

```
ListView(children: <Widget>[
      new Column(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
```

This is the inner ListView

```
Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListView(
                    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _list,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                        leading: ConstrainedBox(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the ScrollController.jumpTo() or ScrollController.animateTo() method to achieve this.

For Ex:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  ScrollController _ScrollController = ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () => _ScrollController.jumpTo(_ScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent));

    return ListView.builder(
      controller: _controller,
        itemCount: 50,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text("ListTile"),));
  }
}
```

You and this on whichever List you want to scroll.
You can also use below code for disable the scroll.

physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()